# How to use Graph API in .net projects?

Tags: .net, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

Im new to calling graph API in .net projects. I'm just using .net 4.8 (not core). From my research online, pages mention the microsoft.authentication.ui, microsoft.authentication.graph, MSAL and Microsoft Graph (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/), but I'm not sure which ones I need.

I don't really plan to get users to sign in and run queries from their account. My app needs to run with a service account and get people information. But only someone with an authenticated account should be able to call it.

Can anyone explain what the above libraries are and which ones I would need?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended library for authenticating against Microsoft Identity (Azure AD) is MSAL.
This supports different types of application and Scenarios

[image: - Single page applications (JavaScript)]

and for using a Protected API which can be accessed by only authenticated users, Please refer [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview)